# HTTPS causing missing views when installing a Net Core 2.1 site in Azure Web APP

Tags: azure, https, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc

I am upgrading a website from MVC5 to Net Core 2.1 and installing in Azure Web Apps.  I want to test the website in Azure before going to production.  I have setup a test website but have not purchased an SSL certificate.  I am getting 404 errors for missing views on the test website but not in VS2017 development.  How can I remove the requirement for an SSL certificate.  The following code is in my Startup.cs.

```
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

I created a test website in VS2017 without HTTPS selected.  I do not see any difference between a site with Https and one without Https.
Also, using the Chrome browser, the site shows as "Secure".  I have never
received a message for a missing SSL certificate.

Bob Neal,

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935730/asp-net-core-2-1-kestrel-how-to-disable-https) SO question may help you.

Comment: I added the UseKestrel(… code with one loopback address set to 5080.  I still receive the 404 errors for missing views. In the Development version, the views are found. In the Production version, the views are missing.

Comment: You should scan your code for querying the IHostingEnvironment interface; see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1). Are you sure nothing is excluded in production?

Comment: I have checked all the code references to IHostingEnvironment for any effect on the production version.  I used the feature in Azure Kudu to see the website.  I can not figure out what was actually published.  Netcore MVC is a lot different from MVC5.2.

Answer (score -1):

Remove app.UseHttpsRedirection(); :)

Comment: In the test website published to azure, I removed the app.UseHttpsRedirection() and still received the 404 errors for missing views.  In the Development version, the views are found.  In the Production version, the views are missing.

Comment: You sure the 404 (not found) exceptions are related to SSL? Are you accessing the website with the http or https url?

Comment: You are correct.  The 404 messages are not caused by SSL.  The problem has turned out to be Httpcontext.session is not working in Production.  I will post another question.  Thank you for your help.