# Accept self-signed certificates in Xamarin Android

Tags: ssl, xamarin, xamarin.android, httpclient

I got a *Xamarin Forms* project and inside the MainPage.xaml.cs file i want to perform a request to my server. The server is written in *ASP.NET Core* 2 and is running with a self-signed certificate.

To buy a certificate isn't a solution for my problem, because customers don't want it and application only running in LAN.

In my MainPage.xaml.cs file the Http-request looks like this:

```
HttpClient m_Client = new HttpClient();
var uri = new Uri(myURL);

var response = await m_Client.GetAsync(uri);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    ...
}
```

So far so good. If I bring the app on **Android** and try to perform the request, Android throws a SSL Exception for not finding a CA for my certificate.

How can I communicate with my server using a self-signed certificate?

I looked up the problem and find a lot of solutions like:

```
ServicePointManager
        .ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
        (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

If you add this code to your MainActivity.cs file in your Android project, it should accept all certificates. But that is not working for me. It seems like this method never gets called.

Any suggestions how to make the communication happen?

Regards

Comment: It doesn't answer your question but how about disabling HTTPS? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935730/asp-net-core-2-1-kestrel-how-to-disable-https

Comment: @CSharpRocks Yes that would be my very last option :)

Comment: You can obtain SSL certs for free from some Certificate Authorities: just one example: https://letsencrypt.org

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes, but didn't I have to enter something like a domain name? I don't have such, the server runs at local area network..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to work on the certificate, which has been discussed in the comments above.

However, I think an option to ignore the certificate validation in code is always faster, and you just need this,

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

For some unknown reasons, you cannot use the global event handler of `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` like you discovered, but `HttpClient` has its own handler.