# How to run asp.net core 2.1 release app at a specific port?

Tags: asp.net-core

Environment: ASP.NET Core 2.1 under Ubuntu 18.04

By default, a newly created asp.net core app runs at http://localhost:5000 and automatically redirects to https://localhost:5001

As I intend to run my app under nginx (and use SSL capabilities of nginx), I would like to run my released app without https and at a specific port, say, 6000.

Post [ASP.NET Core 2.1 + Kestrel (How to disable HTTPS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935730/asp-net-core-2-1-kestrel-how-to-disable-https) explains that one has to simply use "--urls" argument to achieve this.

Here is what I tried:

```
$ dotnet publish --configuration Release
$ dotnet bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/MyApp.dll
```

The app now starts listening at http://localhost:5000 and https://localhost:5001. When I browse to http://localhost:5000, it automatically redirects to https://localhost:5001. So far so good.

Now, I try running at port 6000:

```
$ dotnet bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/MyApp.dll
     --urls="http://localhost:6000"
```

From the messages in the terminal window, the app seems to start listening at http://localhost:6000. However, browsing to this url results in "this site can't be reached" error.

I even tried:

```
$ dotnet bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/MyApp.dll
     --urls="http://localhost:6000,https://localhost:6001"
```

In this case, I get an error that "a path base can only be configured using IApplicationBuilder.UsePathBase()."

Can someone please tell me how I can simply run an application at a specified port? I am hoping I don't need to hard-code port numbers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> "a path base can only be configured using IApplicationBuilder.UsePathBase()."

For this error, it is caused by you use `,` between urls. You need to use `;` to split urls like below:

```
dotnet bin/release/netcoreapp2.1/publish/webapplication3.dll --urls="http://localhost:8000;https://localhost:8001"
```

> I would like to run my released app without https and at a specific port, say, 6000.

For run without https, you need to remove the `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` in `Startup.cs`

**One More Note**

If you fail to access `6000`, I suggest you make a test with `8000`, `port 6000` is disabled by most browsers.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I should have tested a different port than 6000:-(

Answer (score 1):

According to [this piece of documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1#server-urls) it should be something like `dotnet run --urls "http://*:8080"`. So no equals sign in between. But according to the [Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1) documentation there are multiple ways to define a different port e.g. the ASPNETCORE_URLS environment variable.