# Visual Studio 2017 forces sites to load via https, even though ssl is disabled (Dotnet core 2.2)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, iis-express, kestrel-http-server

For some reason, Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.9.12), refuses to load ASP.Net Dotnet Core 2.2 pages in non-ssl.  It automatically appends an s to http as in  https://localhost:15777  even though *Enable SSL* is unchecked and the Launch brower path is set to **http://localhost:15777** (or for Kestrel, it's set to **http://localhost:55333**).

The launchSettings.json file looks like so (as you can see, it's set correctly, but completely ignored).

```
    {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:15777",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:15777",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Nop.Web": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55333"
    }
  }
}
```

This, didn't do this a week ago, and I've scoured posts here and there looking for an answer. Obviously, there is a bug somewhere, so I'm looking for a hack to make Visual Studio, IIS Express or Kestrel work like it's supposed to.
Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core 2.1 + Kestrel (How to disable HTTPS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935730/asp-net-core-2-1-kestrel-how-to-disable-https)

Comment: I saw that, but for Core 2.2, everything changed. Still trying to make sense of why Core 2.2 is so friggin' buggy - never had such a ridiculous problem before.

Comment: "everything changed" is vague. That threads have several answers that are valid even for 3.0 (like `.UseUrls("http://localhost:5000")`).

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't relate to visual studio.
you have to remove the `app.UseHttpsRedirecttion();` in Startup.cs file

also, you may run your Release and because of `app.UseHsts()` it will redirect to https until its time expires.
try to clear your browser security cache.
you can clear hsts security cache by going to `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` and delete the address you want.

Comment: Not using this in the Startup.cs at all.  Is this a default behavior in the dotnet core 2.2 pipeline?

Comment: I removed VS2017 completely, then installed VS2019 and get the same behavior. https - no... matter... what.  It's not defined anywhere - I hard coded the urls, and it insists on doing this.  So, it's not VS, but a bug/feature in Kestrel? Using Core 2.2.3 SDK

Comment: `.UseHttpsRedirection` is now part of `.CreateDefaultBuilder` in 2.2, so this answer itself is invalid.

Comment: I don't believe it is being part of the asp.net core.and i tried with ver 3.0-preview5 and had no problem.

Comment: try with clearing HSTS security cache I just added to the answer.I hope that solve your problem.also you can try using another browser if you dont want to clear hsts cache

Comment: Looks like the problem was with the app I was running - Nopcommerce 4.2.  I created an app from scratch w/ and w/o https and it worked just fine.
This rerouting is occurring somewhere in their code, so I can rule out Kestrel as well.  This question should probably be deleted and a new one opened for Nop (or bug report).

Comment: nopCommerce uses settings stored in the database to redirect to https.you can find it in the place you can add new market(shop).this setting's name is `securitysettings.forcesslforallpages` change it's value to false and it'll be Ok