# Why there are two ports when I run a WebApp

Tags: asp.net-core

All I did was `dotnet new web` command.

This is what it reported when I ran it:

```
 dotnet run
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
```

So my question is why it says now listening on both local host ports 5000 and 5001 ?
When I went to browser, my localhost does work on **5001** but not 5000.
So I am curious to understand that command line output .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because one port is for `http`, and the other one is for `https`

You can disable https listening from launchSettings, or more possible reasons on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935730/asp-net-core-2-1-kestrel-how-to-disable-https)

Comment: oh lol I see now.  Didn't notice the "s" in the other one